# Windows cannot find "mkdir"

Tags: windows, command-line, mkdir, rainmeter

I was trying to create a folder from a Rainmeter skin which didn't work and didn't even yield an error message. Therefore I pasted the command (`mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Foo`) used in Rainmeter into the Execute window (Win+R) and got the error message mentioned in the title. However, when I run it directly from cmd it works fine. If it is the case and `mkdir` cannot be used from outside the command line, I'd appreciate an approach on how to solve this another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since mkdir is an internal command for CMD and not an executable found in PATH, it is only available from CMD. However, you can start a new cmd process and pass the command in as an argument. In the run box you would need to type:

> cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Foo

Answer (score 0):

Or, in response to CConard96, you can make a .cmd file in a text editor, then save and run this code.

```
@mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Foo
```

Comment: But that isn't really practical, is it?